# Failed to resolve: androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling and other modules

Tags: kotlin, gradle, android-jetpack-compose

While building gradle I encounter a warning: Failed to resolve: androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling
and recommends adding Google maven repository but this is already specified in settings.gradle. I tried different versions for compose_ui_version and kotlin compiler extension version. How can I resolve this issue?

```
buildscript {

    ext {
        compose_ui_version = "1.4.0-alpha05"
        }



}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.20' apply false

}
```

and app's build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.bettehomes'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.bettehomes"
        minSdk 25
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerVersion "1.7.20"
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "1.4.0-beta05"

    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    def composeBom = platform("androidx.compose.compose-bom:2022.12.00")
    implementation composeBom
    androidTestImplementation composeBom
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:maps-compose'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3'
    // Android Studio Preview Support

    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem.
Eventually I tried to add the version explicitly like this:

```
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:1.3.2"
```

Notice that 1.3.2 is the version imported by the BOM version you are using.
Obviously it was still not working but at least now I got a more descriptive error message.
It turned out I need `compileSdkVersion 33` (I was using 31).

Since I don't want to increment yet my compileSdkVersion, I will have to downgrade `ui-tooling-preview` to explicitly use version 1.1.1

I can see you are already using `compileSdkVersion 33`, however adding explicitly the version might help you get a more descriptive error message.

Answer (score 1):

Don’t forget to import the BOM in your module’s build.gradle (**module app too**)

```
val composeBom = platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom)
implementation(composeBom)
androidTestImplementation(composeBom)
```

It works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the following into the `buildscript` section inside your project level gradle file?

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: yes, it gives gradle error that setting is already specified at settings.gradle.